# Can't POST with axios using vue and express

Tags: vue.js, post, axios

Using Vue 3.8.3 and express 4.16.4

Trying to send a POST request with Axios to the url /task

The routes are set up in tasks.js

```
router.post("/task", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400)
    res.json({
      error: "Bad Data for POST"
    })
  } else {
    // console.log("req.body.Level: " + req.body.Level);
    Task.create(req.body)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("I am the then... not logging this");
        res.send("Task Added")
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("I am the catch... is logging this");
        res.send("Error: " + err)
      })
  }
})
```

In tasks.js the Task.create the console.log statement in the .catch(...) is being logged but not the console.log statement in the .then(...)

I have it working for delete, get and put, but post is not working

The component has a method,

```
addNewTask() {
      axios.post("/api/task", {
          Level: this.Levelname,
          Year: this.Yearname,
          Question: this.Questionname,
          Answer: this.Answername,
          Topic: this.Topicname,
          Sub_topic: this.Sub_topicname,
          Question_type: this.Question_typename,
          Marks: this.Marksname,
          Question_number: this.Question_numbername,
          Part: this.Partname,
          Sub_part: this.Sub_partname
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.Levelname = ''
          this.Yearname = ''
          this.Questionname = ''
          this.Answername = ''
          this.Topicname = ''
          this.Sub_partname = ''
          this.Question_typename = ''
          this.Marksname = ''
          this.Question_numbername = ''
          this.Partname = ''
          this.Sub_part = ''
          this.getTasks()
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
```

This project uses an express backend, server.js

```
var express = require("express")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")

var tasks = require("./routes/tasks")
var cors = require("cors")

var port = 3000

var app = express()
app.use(cors())

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}))

app.use("/api", tasks)

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server started on port ' + port)
})
```

In the commandline the express server is giving,

```
 INSERT INTO `physics_tbls` (`id`,`Level`,`Year`,`Question`,`Answer`,`Topic`,`Sub_topic`,`Question_type`,`Marks`,`Question_number`,`Part`,`Sub_part`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
```

So clearly the values are not getting there.

Is there something I am missing here?

The put request for updating the database works perfectly. Here is an example of that,

In tasks.js

```
router.put("/task/:id", (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    res.status(400)
    res.json({
      error: "Bad Data....!"
    })
  } else {
    Task.update({
        Level: req.body.Level,
        Year: req.body.Year,
        Question: req.body.Question,
        Answer: req.body.Answer,
        Topic: req.body.Topic,
        Sub_topic: req.body.Sub_topic,
        Question_type: req.body.Question_type,
        Marks: req.body.Marks,
        Question_number: req.body.Question_number,
        Part: req.body.Part,
        Sub_part: req.body.Sub_part
      }, {
        where: {
          id: req.params.id
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        res.send("Task Updated")
      })
      .error(err => res.send(err))
  }
})
```

and in the component,

```
updateTask(id) {
      // axios.put(`/api/task/${this.id}`, {
      axios.put('/api/task/' + id, {
          Level: this.Levelname,
          Year: this.Yearname,
          Question: this.Questionname,
          Answer: this.Answername,
          Topic: this.Topicname,
          Sub_part: this.Sub_partname,
          Question_type: this.Question_typename,
          Marks: this.Marksname,
          Question_number: this.Question_numbername,
          Part: this.Partname,
          Sub_part: this.Sub_partname
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.Levelname = ''
          this.Yearname = ''
          this.Questionname = ''
          this.Answername = ''
          this.Topicname = ''
          this.Sub_topicname = ''
          this.Question_typename = ''
          this.Marksname = ''
          this.Question_numbername = ''
          this.Partname = ''
          this.Sub_partname = ''
          this.isEdit = false
          this.getTasks()
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't work about it? Do you get an error or does the callback function body never get hit?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. It is not posting to the database.  The addNewTask() function is being called. And I know that I know that Levelname and Yearname are also being passed to it.

Comment: @Grillparzer In tasks.js, in the Task.create the console.log statement in the .catch(...) is being logged but not the console.log statement in the .then(...) So this is specifically where it is failing.

Comment: Could you try and log the error in the catch() and add it to your post?

Comment: Yes that gives Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Marks' at row 1

Comment: This makes sense as Marks is a blank character and it is expecting an integer. So replaced, '' for Marks with an integer and I an error

Comment: Adding an integer value to the Marks and Question_number columns has solved the problem. It is now posting to the db. Thanks for your help

Comment: Kudo's that you managed to solve it yourself :)